# Apache config: Return 404 for single <Location>

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, http-status-code-404

Is it possible to let Apache automatically return a 404 page for a single URL using the Location tag?

```
<Location "/some/url">
    # ???
</Location>
```

Solutions without mod_rewrite or any other modules preferred.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The only solution "without any modules", is to not have the resource exist. If the location doesn't exist, then it Apache will return a 404.

Otherwise, you will need to use mod_alias or mod_rewrite. mod_alias is the simpler and more efficient solution:

```
Redirect 404 /your/url/path
```

You use this inside your vhost, there is no need to put it in a Location block.

You can also use the `RedirectMatch` directive if you don't want to match URLs below `/your/url/path`:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/your/url/path$
```

This and more can be read in the [mod_alias documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html)

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately this will also return 404 for anything matching '/your/url/path/*', which is a problem for me.

Comment: @Andi: You should be more specific in your questions.

Comment: Sorry for that ;) The `RedirectMatch` solution works like a charm.

Comment: It is not working at all for me. And according to the documentation 404 is no valid status for Redirect / RedirectMatch

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can use a `RewriteRule` for this (make sure your RewriteEngine is enabled):

```
RewriteRule ^/forbidden_ /nonexistent [L]
```

Got this information from "[return 404 for specific url?](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/200603.mbox/%3C44198380.9050605@googlemail.com%3E)" in the Apache mailing list archives.

Comment: Well, I'd like to have a generic non-rewrite solution. I know the mod_rewrite solution already.

Comment: People are so used to use `mod_rewrite` for what it was never intended for… your solution will not work if website uses `FallbackResource` directive. `Redirect 404 /path`, however, will.